How to generate a flattened list of all members and types in a C++ struct or class?
I’m trying to generate a flattened output of all the members and their types for a given C++ struct or class, including inherited members.
For example, given the following classes:
class ParentClass {
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

class MemberA {
    int foo;
    float bar;
};

class MemberB {
    int baz;
    float bot;
};

class MyClass : ParentClass {
    MemberA memberA1;
    MemberA memberA2;
    MemberB memberB;
    int top;
};

I’d like to produce output like this:
MyClass(ParentClass).a(int) 
MyClass(ParentClass).b(std::string)
MyClass.memberA1(MemberA).foo(int)
MyClass.memberA1(MemberA).bar(float)
MyClass.memberA2(MemberA).foo(int)
MyClass.memberA2(MemberA).bar(float)
MyClass.memberB(MemberB).baz(int)
MyClass.memberB(MemberB).bot(float)
MyClass.top(int)

The goal is to create a comprehensive, easy-to-parse text-based output that can be used in other tools.
What I’ve tried so far:

Parsing PDB files: I’m working in Visual Studio 2019, but this approach hasn’t yielded a satisfying result.
Using DIA in C++: However, I encountered COM issues, potentially due to company IT policies.
Using Python's pdbparse library: Unfortunately, I received an "Unsupported File Type" error. It seems the library isn't well-maintained for newer PDB formats.
C++20 Reflection: I attempted to use reflection features in C++20, but didn’t achieve the desired results.

My next steps:

Digging deeper into C++20 reflection, though it seems complex.
Custom Doxygen generation, since Doxygen already provides comprehensive documentation features.

Question:
Are there any other approaches I should consider? Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated!

There's no reflection in c++20 afaik. The current state of reflection in C++20

Another approach to consider ( that quite a few tools take ) is to define the classes / structures in your own meta-language and generate the C++ from that language and also use the meta-language in the other tools.

Do you want to extract this information from the source files or from .pdb ? If from source, you are basically looking for a C++ parser, perhaps clang/llvm could be of use?

Which vesrin of doxygen did you use? Did you have a look at the possibility of XML output (GENERATE_XML=YES) and parse this output?

@user12002570 that is what I concluded, all tools used to achieved that were tricky and far from what reflection looks like in languages that truly implements it.

@RichardCritten : Sadly My code base is huge, I cannot chose that way.

@albert : thank you for the idea, i'm generating it right now and see what can be done.

@Quimby: I can try that indeed, thank you for the idea

clReflect might be an option - that allows you to generate metadata from the source code and then access it at runtime: Small Example - It does however require tagging the types you want reflection info for. (you could however probably change its code to always return PAR_Reflect from ParseAttributes so that everything will get reflected even without attributes)
